# What is the limit of the value list in MySQL's PARTITION BY LIST?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

When partitioning by list

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (...)
PARTITION BY LIST(my_column)
( PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (xxx),
  ...
);
```

what is the limit of xxx?

Comment: In my experience, if you have to ask, then probably no long enough; especially if the list was so long (or "dynamic") that you couldn't just see if your server rejects it.

Comment: Zero.  My opinion is that `PARTITION BY LIST` is useless for virtually all applications.  You can get the same or better performance with a suitable `INDEX`.  Please provide some clues of what type of app and what selects you are doing.

Comment: Any suitable `INDEX` will have a O(log n) complexity, this also applies on partitions. So working with 10M rows partitions should be better than working with a non partitioned 300M rows table, since I know which partition to use. Is that right ?

Comment: There is overhead to using partitions, they affect how the data is physically stored; as such, they can negatively effect any queries "across" them. To use your "10M partitions" proposition for demonstration, imagine the overhead of opening all 10 million partition files vs examining one file. An index might reduce the number of partitions inspected; but assuming the best index for a certain query is not related to the partitioning criteria, there is still probably a significant number of them that will need opened.

Comment: Also, do you have any documentation actually suggesting partition access is O(log N)? The very fact values must be specified suggests to me it is not. It's likely it is O(M) where M is the list of values, after which point each partition identified must be searched in O(log (N/M)) _assuming appropriate indexes_; making the total exercise something like O(M*log(N/M)).

Comment: In my specific case, partitions are better because 1) less rows have to be accessed 2) separate MyISAM partitions can be written _*simultaneously*_ (4x PCIE SSD accessed by 4 separate threads). But this is not my initial question for which I don't know the answer, so I will assume that you don't know it either ;)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by 10M row partitions; it sounded like you meant 10M partitions, not partitions that held 1/30th the rows of an unpartitioned table's store. The ability to partition across storage devices is one of the core benefits of partitioning; but that still does not lead to the idea that an indefinite number of partitions (or values) need to be specified. You might want to consider that the "argument" to LIST() need not be a bare column.

Comment: An expression like `LIST(parent_id % 4)` could be used to spread commonly grouped data across 4 partitions... and the value lists can be used if you expect an uneven distribution of the values resulting from the expression used. _(Obviously, expressions like `id % 4` usually have a relatively uniform distribution; but other expressions may not.)_